# Error integrating Salesforce to Boomi

Tags: boomi

I'm unable to connect to boomi from salesforce outbound message. We have used salesforce connector listen operation, however we are getting (503)Service Unavailable. There are no firewall restrictions in the local atom and even we have encoded the boomi_auth with base 64.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100998/error-integrating-salesforce-with-boomi.

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be an issue with Port which is assign to Boomi Local Atom or Some Security Token which we generate from Boomi Atom. You can regenerate it from Boomi Atom and follow these steps

Define you URL on Boomi Atom if you are using it on Local Machine.

https://test.boomi.com/;boomi_auth=

OperationURL - From the Web Services Server Operation URL, which will start with /ws/…

AuthString - A Base64 encoded value of – :

For Account Id 
1. Click on Setup Page
2. Then Click on Account Information
3. Copy Account Id

For Security Token
1. Click on Atom Management 
2. Click on Atom and then click on Shared Web Server Setting
3. Select Authentication Basic and Generate Security Token
4. Copy Security Token

Just Write AccountId and Secuirty Token
:
and generate Base64Encode from the below link and add to Boomi Atom URL

http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64encode/

Hope this will help you 
Thanks